# & in Typescript types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Found a [Typescript definition file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sweetalert) that declares the below as the types required for a function input.

```
settings: Settings & AlertModalSettings
```

**How to declare type that can be use as a valid input for the above?**

Tried the below, it's not working

```
let a: SweetAlert.Settings = {

};
let b: SweetAlert.PromtModalSettings = {

};

swal(a & b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`settings` has a type which is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

The variable/function parameter parameter must be of type `Settings & AlertModalSettings` and must implement **all** members of both types

```
function swal(a: Settings & AlertModalSettings) {
....
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `a & b`, since the `&` in that case is the [bitwise AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) which acts on numbers.

If you already have a `SweetAlert.Settings` object and a `SweetAlert.PromtModalSettings` object, you can merge them with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or the [spread operator for object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
declare let a: SweetAlert.Settings;
declare let b: SweetAlert.PromtModalSettings;
const abObjectAssign = Object.assign({}, a, b);
swal(abObjectAssign); // okay

const abSpread = { ...a, ...b };
swal(abSpread); // okay
```

If you don't have objects `a` and `b` lying around and want to pass an object literal to `swal()`, all you have to do is give it one which matches both `SweetAlert.Settings` and `SweetAlert.PromtModalSettings`:

```
swal({
  title: 'title', // required in Settings
  allowOutsideClick: false // optional in PromtModalSettings
}); // okay
```

Hope that helps; good luck!